# Simulating noise signals in Multisim

Tags: noise, simulation, multisim

I would like to simulate the effect of noise in a circuit built in Multisim so that I can make better component choices to improve my design. The main source of concern for me is that the circuit will be affected by noise created by ambient sources of electromagnetic radiation since there will be IR LED/phototransistor pair in the circuit, where the IR LED will modulate a 20kHz square wave signal. Can anybody make any suggestions as to how I would do this?

Comment: Doesn't MultiSim contain a noise source and noise analysis mode?

Comment: @JoelB - I don't know, I've never attempted to simulate the effect of noise in a circuit before, so thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.  Check [here](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/12789) for instructions.